# How to create a pareto distribution prediction function?

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, trigonometry

[image: pareto distribution prediction]

I am trying to create a pareto distribution prediction function:

```js
const paretoDistributionPrediction = (numberOfPeople, personAtIndex) => {

    let prediction = '?'

    if (numberOfPeople === 2) {
        prediction = personAtIndex === 1 ? 80 : 20;
    }
    
    return prediction + "%";
}

paretoDistributionPrediction(2, 1)
```

The perfect shape that gives the results I want is a cycloid rotated 45deg to fit without its cups in a square.

The right side of the square is always divided in equal parts by `numberOfPeople`. From the interaction with the cycloid curve, the lines perpendicularly divide the bottom side of the square. Then I want to know how much is in percentage a division from the bottom side of the square for `personAtIndex` (index of an item in `numberOfPeople`).

**After the right side of the square is divided in equal parts by horizontal lines, how to find out the size of the corresponded division on the bottom side of the square after the incident lines have perpendicular intersected with the cycloid curve?**

In the first drawing you can see how I reached the conclusion that a cycloid is the shape that will give an 80 20 ratio output.

Bellow images are expected outputs for `paretoDistributionPrediction=f` function: `f(2,1)=80%`, `f(2,2)=20%`, `f(3,1)=68%`,`f(3,2)=23%`,`f(3,3)=9%`,`f(4,1)=58%`,`f(4,2)=22%`,`f(4,4)=7%`.

[image: population = 2]
[image: population = 3]
[image: population = 4]
[image: population = 5]

Comment: This is a math question rather than programming.

Comment: [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/nkmd9veq/) a possible solution to the problem you posted, if I understood the way you set up the cycloid, although I don't get what `population` and `at` mean; I used the input percentage: an input percentage of 50% results in an output percentage of 20%, etc. [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/eyxbaozh/) the graphical representation of the cycloid with the parameters used; and [this](https://jsfiddle.net/f0zu7w4b/) is the code I used to compute the parameters of the cycloid. Please let me know if this is what you are looking for, and if not, what am I missing.

Comment: @kikon there are some very helpful clues in your code examples that will help me out. While I study them I updated the question with some more details.

Comment: Your edit makes it clear what the two parameters meant, so I posted the solution with those adjustments, and the full description, to make it clear how I took the cycloid. There are possibly other ways to go with a cycloid, or we can try other curves as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### A solution

A cycloid that conforms to the description of the question is given by the
parametric coordinates:

```js
const r = 0.3107954365513382, dr = 0.22339354437585907;
const sin45deg = Math.sqrt(2)/2;
const x = t => r * sin45deg * (1 - t + Math.sin(t) - Math.cos(t) + Math.PI) + dr,
    y = t => - r * sin45deg * (1 + t - Math.sin(t) - Math.cos(t) - Math.PI) - dr,
```

I'll describe later how I derived those equations and computed the
parameters.

Now, regardless of the actual curve that is used, if it
defined parametrically, the *mathematics* involved for determining
the parameters of the distributions involve getting the value of `y`
that corresponds to a certain `x` on the curve - it means solve the
equation `y(t) = y` to get the parameter `t` and then use that parameter
to compute `x(t)`.

For the case of the cycloid, as well as most other curves, the solution
of the equation `y(t) = y` cannot be derived in closed form, so it has
to be computed numerically. The numerical method I have chosen
is [Newton's method](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NewtonsMethod.html);
it requires the derivative of `y(t)`, `y'(t)`, which I implemented in
the function `yd(t)`.

With these, the solution to the problem in question is this:

```js
const r = 0.3107954365513382, dr = 0.22339354437585907;
const sin45deg = Math.sqrt(2)/2;
const x = t => r * sin45deg * (1 - t + Math.sin(t) - Math.cos(t) + Math.PI) + dr,
    y = t => r * sin45deg * (1 + t - Math.sin(t) - Math.cos(t) - Math.PI) + dr,
    yd = t => r * sin45deg * (1 - Math.cos(t) + Math.sin(t));

const getXForY = y0 => {
    let t = Math.PI, yt = y(t) - y0;
    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        const tNext = t - yt / yd(t);
        yt = y(tNext) - y0;
        const dt = tNext - t;
        t = tNext;
        if(Math.abs(yt) < 1e-20 || Math.abs(dt) < 1e-15){
            break;
        }
    }
    return x(t);
}

const paretoDistributionPredictionFor = (numberOfPeople, personAtIndex) => {
    if(personAtIndex < 1 || personAtIndex > numberOfPeople){
        return null;
    }
    const fracInStart = (personAtIndex - 1)/numberOfPeople,
        fracInEnd = personAtIndex/numberOfPeople;
    const fracOutStart = 1 - getXForY(1 - fracInStart),
        fracOutEnd = 1 - getXForY(1 - fracInEnd),
        fracOutDiff = -fracOutEnd + fracOutStart;

    return (fracOutDiff * 100).toFixed(2).replace(/\.0+$/, '')+'%';
}

console.log('f(2, 1) = ' + paretoDistributionPredictionFor(2, 1));
console.log('f(2, 1) = ' + paretoDistributionPredictionFor(2, 2));

console.log(Array(30).fill('-').join(''));

console.log('f(3, 1) = ' + paretoDistributionPredictionFor(3, 1));
console.log('f(3, 2) = ' + paretoDistributionPredictionFor(3, 2));
console.log('f(3, 3) = ' + paretoDistributionPredictionFor(3, 3));

console.log(Array(30).fill('-').join(''));

console.log('f(4, 1) = ' + paretoDistributionPredictionFor(4, 1));
console.log('f(4, 2) = ' + paretoDistributionPredictionFor(4, 2));
console.log('f(4, 3) = ' + paretoDistributionPredictionFor(4, 3));
console.log('f(4, 4) = ' + paretoDistributionPredictionFor(4, 4));
```

also as [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ep9q40z6/)

---

#### The cycloid

The standard equation of the [cycloid](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cycloid.html)
is

```js
x = t => r * (t - Math.sin(t));
y = t => r * (1 - Math.cos(t));
```

These equations give a cycloid that passes through
the point `(0, 0)`, `(PI*r, 2*r)` - the maximum, `(2*PI*r, 0)`.

To make it symmetrical with respect to the origin (more precisely with
respect to the `y` axis), we have to subtract `PI * r` from `x`

```js
x = t => r * (t - Math.sin(t) - Math.PI);
y = t => r * (1 - Math.cos(t));
```

This curve passes through `(-PI*r, 0)`, `(0, 2*r)` - the maximum,
and `(PI*r, 0)`.

The next step is to [rotate](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RotationMatrix.html)
the cycloid by `-3*PI/4`, that is 145 degrees clockwise. This gives
the equations:

```js
const sin45deg = Math.sqrt(2)/2;
const x = t => r * sin45deg * (1 - t + Math.sin(t) - Math.cos(t) + Math.PI),
    y = t => - r * sin45deg * (1 + t - Math.sin(t) - Math.cos(t) - Math.PI),
```

These would allow one to compute `r` such that the cycloid passes through
the points (1, 0) and (0, -1); due to symmetry, only one condition has to be
verified. This gives `r = 0.43077140606812125` (see below on how I computed
`r` and `dr`, for an outline of the method to derive `r`).

The problem with this curve is that it doesn't pass through the point
`(0.8, -0.5)`, which would make it verify the 80:20 ratio of Pareto fame.
The `x` value that corresponds to `y = -0.5` (50%) is `x = 0.7094`,
which would make it 71:29. This can be seen in the snippet below
(get the cursor near the cycloid to get other ratio values).

```js
const r = 0.43077140606812125;
const sin45deg = Math.sqrt(2)/2;
const x = t => r * sin45deg * (1 - t + Math.sin(t) - Math.cos(t) + Math.PI),
    y = t => r * sin45deg * (1 + t - Math.sin(t) - Math.cos(t) - Math.PI),
    yd = t => r * sin45deg * (1 - Math.cos(t) + Math.sin(t));

const getXForY = y0 => {
    let t = Math.PI, yt = y(t) - y0;
    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        const tNext = t - yt / yd(t);
        yt = y(tNext) - y0;
        const dt = tNext - t;
        t = tNext;
        if(Math.abs(yt) < 1e-20 || Math.abs(dt) < 1e-15){
            break;
        }
    }
    return  x(t);
}

const linspace = function(x1, x2, n){
    return Array.from({length: n}, (_, i) => x1 + (x2 - x1) * i / (n - 1));
}
const N = 100;

const cycloidPoints = (() => {
    const ta = linspace(0, 2 * Math.PI, N);
    return ta.map(t => ({x: x(t), y: -y(t)}));
})();
const cycloidXAxis = [cycloidPoints[0], cycloidPoints[N-1]];
const squarePoints = [{x:0, y: 0}, {x: 1, y: 0}, {x: 1, y: -1}, {x: 0, y: -1}, {x: 0, y: 0}];

const pareto = getXForY(0.5);
const paretoPoints = [{x: 1, y: -0.5}, {x: pareto, y: -0.5}, {x: pareto, y: -1}];

const data = {
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Cycloid',
            data: cycloidPoints,
            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 26, 104, 1)',
        },
        {
            label: 'Cycloid x-axis',
            data: cycloidXAxis,
            borderColor: 'rgba(70, 140, 40, 1)',
            borderDash: [5, 4],
            borderWidth: 2
        },
        {
            label: 'square',
            data: squarePoints,
            borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
        },
        {
            data: paretoPoints,
            borderColor: 'rgba(40, 70, 140, 1)',
        }]
}
const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data,
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        pointRadius: 0,
        borderWidth: 1,
        tension: 0,
        scales: {
            x: {
                type: 'linear',
            }
        },
        interaction: {
            intersect: false,
            mode: "nearest"
        },
        plugins: {
            tooltip: {
                filter({datasetIndex, parsed: {x, y}}){
                    return datasetIndex === 0 && x >= 0 && x <= 1 && -y >= 0 && -y <= 1;
                },

                callbacks: {
                    title(){
                        return '';
                    },
                    label(context){
                        if(context.datasetIndex !== 0){
                            return null;
                        }
                        const {x, y} = context.parsed;
                        if(x < 0 || x > 1 || -y < 0 || -y > 1){
                            return ''
                        }
                        return `${(-y*100).toFixed(0)}% => ${(x*100).toFixed(0)}%`;
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                labels: {
                    usePointStyle: true,
                    pointStyle: 'line',
                    filter(a){
                        return a.text;
                    }
                }
            },
            annotation: {
                annotations: {
                    label1: {
                        type: "label",
                        xValue: pareto,
                        yValue: -0.5,
                        position: 'end',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        borderDash: [4, 6],
                        content: `50% => ${(pareto * 100).toFixed(0)}%`
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

const chart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('chart'),
    config
);

// set approx equal scales
const containerEl = document.getElementById('container');
const xRange = chart.scales.x.max - chart.scales.x.min,
    yRange = chart.scales.y.max - chart.scales.y.min,
    xg = chart.chartArea.width,
    yg = chart.chartArea.height,
    dx = containerEl.offsetWidth - xg,
    dy = containerEl.offsetHeight - yg,
    scaleX = xg/xRange,
    scaleY = yg/yRange;

const reScaleX = scaleX / Math.min(scaleX, scaleY),
    reScaleY = scaleY / Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);


containerEl.style.width = (containerEl.offsetWidth / reScaleX + dx * (1 - 1/reScaleX))+"px";
containerEl.style.height = (containerEl.offsetHeight / reScaleY  + dy * (1 - 1/reScaleY))+"px";
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-annotation@3.0.1/dist/chartjs-plugin-annotation.min.js"></script>

<div style="height:500px" id="container">
    <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
```

also as [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pd1v0x6q/)

To address this issue, I added a translation of the cycloid, after
the rotation. To keep symmetry, the translation has to be along the
`x = -y` line; this would add a `dr` to x, while, `y = y - dr`. With
this new parameter, the equations of the cycloid are:

```js
x = t => r * sin45deg * (1 - t + Math.sin(t) - Math.cos(t) + Math.PI) + dr;
y = t => - r * sin45deg * (1 + t - Math.sin(t) - Math.cos(t) - Math.PI) - dr;
```

Now we have two equations to solve for the two unknowns, `r` and `dr`: the
first equation comes again from the condition that the cycloid passes
through the point `x=1, y=0`, while the second is to verify the 80:20
ration, that is that the cycloid passes through the point `x=0.8, y=-0.5`.

With these, we get the values of the parameters `r = 0.3107954365513382, dr = 0.22339354437585907`
(see below how). Here's the cycloid in this case:

```js
const r = 0.3107954365513382, dr = 0.22339354437585907;
const sin45deg = Math.sqrt(2)/2;
const x = t => r * sin45deg * (1 - t + Math.sin(t) - Math.cos(t) + Math.PI) + dr,
    y = t => r * sin45deg * (1 + t - Math.sin(t) - Math.cos(t) - Math.PI) + dr,
    yd = t => r * sin45deg * (1 - Math.cos(t) + Math.sin(t));

const getXForY = y0 => {
    let t = Math.PI, yt = y(t) - y0;
    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        const tNext = t - yt / yd(t);
        yt = y(tNext) - y0;
        const dt = tNext - t;
        t = tNext;
        if(Math.abs(yt) < 1e-20 || Math.abs(dt) < 1e-15){
            break;
        }
    }
    return  x(t);
}

const linspace = function(x1, x2, n){
    return Array.from({length: n}, (_, i) => x1 + (x2 - x1) * i / (n - 1));
}
const N = 100;

const cycloidPoints = (() => {
    const ta = linspace(0, 2 * Math.PI, N);
    return ta.map(t => ({x: x(t), y: -y(t)}));
})();
const cycloidXAxis = [cycloidPoints[0], cycloidPoints[N-1]];
const squarePoints = [{x:0, y: 0}, {x: 1, y: 0}, {x: 1, y: -1}, {x: 0, y: -1}, {x: 0, y: 0}];

const pareto = getXForY(0.5);
const paretoPoints = [{x: 1, y: -0.5}, {x: pareto, y: -0.5}, {x: pareto, y: -1}];


const data = {
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Cycloid',
            data: cycloidPoints,
            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 26, 104, 1)',
        },
        {
            label: 'Cycloid x-axis',
            data: cycloidXAxis,
            borderColor: 'rgba(70, 140, 40, 1)',
            borderDash: [5, 4],
            borderWidth: 2
        },
        {
            label: 'square',
            data: squarePoints,
            borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
        },
        {
            data: paretoPoints,
            borderColor: 'rgba(40, 70, 140, 1)',
        }]
}
const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data,
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        pointRadius: 0,
        borderWidth: 1,
        tension: 0,
        scales: {
            x: {
                type: 'linear',
            }
        },
        interaction: {
            intersect: false,
            mode: "nearest"
        },
        plugins: {
            tooltip: {
                filter({datasetIndex, parsed: {x, y}}){
                    return datasetIndex === 0 && x >= 0 && x <= 1 && -y >= 0 && -y <= 1;
                },

                callbacks: {
                    title(){
                        return '';
                    },
                    label(context){
                        if(context.datasetIndex !== 0){
                            return null;
                        }
                        const {x, y} = context.parsed;
                        if(x < 0 || x > 1 || -y < 0 || -y > 1){
                            return ''
                        }
                        return `${(-y*100).toFixed(0)}% => ${(x*100).toFixed(0)}%`;
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                labels: {
                    usePointStyle: true,
                    pointStyle: 'line',
                    filter(a){
                        return a.text;
                    }
                }
            },
            annotation: {
                annotations: {
                    label1: {
                        type: "label",
                        xValue: pareto,
                        yValue: -0.5,
                        position: 'end',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        borderDash: [4, 6],
                        content: `50% => ${(pareto * 100).toFixed(0)}%`
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

const chart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('chart'),
    config
);

// set approx equal scales
const containerEl = document.getElementById('container');
const xRange = chart.scales.x.max - chart.scales.x.min,
    yRange = chart.scales.y.max - chart.scales.y.min,
    xg = chart.chartArea.width,
    yg = chart.chartArea.height,
    dx = containerEl.offsetWidth - xg,
    dy = containerEl.offsetHeight - yg,
    scaleX = xg/xRange,
    scaleY = yg/yRange;

const reScaleX = scaleX / Math.min(scaleX, scaleY),
    reScaleY = scaleY / Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);


containerEl.style.width = (containerEl.offsetWidth / reScaleX + dx * (1 - 1/reScaleX))+"px";
containerEl.style.height = (containerEl.offsetHeight / reScaleY  + dy * (1 - 1/reScaleY))+"px";
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-annotation@3.0.1/dist/chartjs-plugin-annotation.min.js"></script>

<div style="height:500px" id="container">
    <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
```

also as [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ygLobas/)

---

#### Computing `r` and `dr`

This is of little consequence for the rest of the discussion, but I'll
give the code and description for the sake of completeness.

I computed the values of `r` and `dr`, from the equations `x(t) = 0, y(t) = 1`
and `x(t) = 0.5` and `y(t) = -0.8` as described in the previous section.
For any pair of values for `r` and `dr` we can compute four values of
`t` that the four equations above: `x(t1) = 0`, `y(t2) = 1`, `x(t3) = 0.5`,
`y(t4) = -0.8`. Computing the four `t`s is done as described in the
first section, by using Newton's method.

Now, the first two equations of the four above should come together, that
is *for the same `t`*: `t1 = t2`; the same goes for the last two, we
intend to find the `r` and `dr` that give `t3 = t4`. This means we
have our two equations as:

```js
t1(r, dr) - t2(r, dr) = 0
t3(r, dr) - t4(r, dr) = 0
```

This system is also solved using Newton's method, with the difference that
the differentials are computed numerically.

For the method to be convergent, one has to start with good initial values;
fortunately, there is the cycloid graphic above, where we could play
with the values of parameters with visual feedback, such that we obtained
good initial values.

Here's the code:

```js
const sin45deg = Math.sqrt(2)/2;
const xr = (r, dr) => (t => r * sin45deg * (1 - t + Math.sin(t) - Math.cos(t) + Math.PI) + dr),
    xdr = (r, dr) => (t => r * sin45deg * (-1 + Math.cos(t) + Math.sin(t))),
    yr = (r, dr) => (t => r * sin45deg * (1 + t - Math.sin(t) - Math.cos(t) - Math.PI) + dr),
    ydr = (r, dr) => (t => r * sin45deg * (1 - Math.cos(t) + Math.sin(t)));

const getTForX = (r, dr, x0, nMax = 100) => {
    const x = xr(r, dr), xd = xdr(r, dr);
    let t = Math.PI, xt = x(t) - x0;
    const a_dt = [], a_xt = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < nMax; i++){
        const tNext = t - xt / xd(t);
        xt = x(tNext) - x0;
        const dt = tNext - t;
        t = tNext;
        a_dt.push(dt);
        a_xt.push(xt);
        if(Math.abs(xt) < 1e-20 || Math.abs(dt) < 1e-12){
            break;
        }
        else if(i === nMax-1){
            console.error({r, dr, x0}, {a_xt, a_dt});
            throw 'not converging on x; choose different initial values';
        }
    }
    return t;
}

const getTForY = (r, dr, y0, nMax = 100) => {
    const y = yr(r, dr), yd = ydr(r, dr);
    let t = Math.PI, yt = y(t) - y0;
    const a_dt = [], a_yt = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < nMax; i++){
        const tNext = t - yt / yd(t);
        yt = y(tNext) - y0;
        const dt = tNext - t;
        a_dt.push(dt);
        a_yt.push(yt);
        t = tNext;
        if(Math.abs(yt) < 1e-20 || Math.abs(dt) < 1e-12){
            break;
        }
        else if(i === nMax-1){
            console.error({r, dr, y0}, {a_yt, a_dt});
            throw 'not converging on x; choose different initial values';
        }
    }
    return t;
}

const x0 = 1, y0 = 0;
const x1 = 0.8, y1 = 0.5;

const eq0 = (r, dr) => /*Math.abs*/(getTForX(r, dr, x0) - getTForY(r, dr, y0));
const eq1 = (r, dr) => /*Math.abs*/(getTForX(r, dr, x1) - getTForY(r, dr, y1));

const eps_diff = 1e-3;
const J0 = (r, dr) => {
    const v0 = eq0(r, dr);
    return [(eq0(r+eps_diff, dr)-v0)/eps_diff, (eq0(r, dr+eps_diff)-v0)/eps_diff];
}
const J1 = (r1, dr1) => {
    const v1 = eq1(r1, dr1);
    return [(eq1(r1+eps_diff, dr1)-v1)/eps_diff, (eq1(r1, dr1+eps_diff)-v1)/eps_diff];
}

const solveMain = (r0, dr0, nMax = 20) => {
    let r = r0, dr = dr0;
    let df0 = eq0(r, dr),
        df1 = eq1(r, dr);
    for(let i = 0; i < nMax; i++){
        const [J00, J01] = J0(r, dr),
            [J10, J11] = J1(r, dr);

        const det = J00 * J11 - J01 * J10;
        const delta_r = -(df0 * J11 - df1 * J01) / det,
            delta_dr = -(-J10 * df0 + J00 * df1) / det;

        r = r + delta_r;
        dr = dr + delta_dr;
        df0 = eq0(r, dr);
        df1 = eq1(r, dr);

        if(Math.max(Math.abs(df0), Math.abs(df1)) < 1e-20 ||
            Math.max(Math.abs(delta_r), Math.abs(delta_dr)) < 1e-12){
            break;
        }
        else if(i === nMax-1){
            throw 'not converging globally; choose different initial values';
        }
    }
    return ({r, dr});
}

// initial values can be obtained by playing with these params on the graphic
console.log(solveMain(0.3, 0.25));
```

also as [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/twed05qc/)

**Note** In the code in the first section, I used `-y` instead of `y`,
to simplify computation. Graphically it would mean flipping the chart
along x axis, or moving the action from quadrant 4 to quadrant 1.